# Drawing tri-axial ellipsoid and intersecting it with a sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, intersections

I would like to draw a tri-axial ellipsoid (that is, an ellipsoid with three different main axes). I'd also like to draw a sphere in the same picture, showing the curves of intersection between the sphere and the ellipsoid. I have seen TikZ code that makes a ellipsoid, but it's always an ellipsoid of rotation, so with the same x and y size.

In principle, it is enough to have solid shapes for the ellipsoid and the sphere, longitudinal and latitudinal planes are not necessary.

Could anyone help me with this/show me some example code for a tri-axial ellipsoid?

I would prefer to have a 3D image, e.g. like [Example: Stereographic and cylindrical map projections](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/). At the moment, it looks something like this (the white lines are artefacts of the jpg conversion),

[image]

but I'd like to improve it.

Comment: I guess that the first question is: how do you want to convey the three-dimensionality of the shapes?  By colours?  By lines?  For example, one could quite easily draw the three intersections of the ellipsoid with the axial planes.  Would that be enough (for that shape)?

Comment: with `pst-solides3d` it is a two-liner ...

Comment: instead of posting an "answer" containing further information, please edit the original question, I just did it for you. Or post a comment with additional information. The space below is reserved for answers.

Comment: @Herbert: Could you provide a "two-liner" answer?

Comment: With asymptote this is absolutely straightforward.